# В чем преимущества и недостатки div, anchor и button?

Tags: html, css

кто что использует для отображения кнопок на странице (без тэга form)

div, a или button ?

`ИМХО`

div удобней:

- блочный
- не надо обрабатывать href
- лучше стилизуется

чем button и anchor могут быть предпочтительней div?

Comment: Почитайте про семантику html

Comment: с удовольствием, дайте ссылку на освещение конкретно этого вопроса

Comment: Око за око - ничем